# I want to replace fields with STRING with correct data type FLOAT64 in BigQuery. How do I do it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update, sqldatatypes, alter-table

I am new to learning Data Analysis. I have a field in my BigQuery dataset named Unemployment_rate that should be FLOAT64. However, some fields that should be 0 are represented as 'NaN', which is STRING. How do I use the function UPDATE TABLE to update the table to be consistent with other cells under that field as a FLOAT64?

```
UPDATE 
  `personal-portfolio-397412.capstone_project.2023_HY_Top_950_Youtubers`
SET Unemployment_rate = 0.0
WHERE Unemployment_rate = 'NaN'
```

I expected the rows under Unemployment_rate field filled as 'NaN' to be standardized to the correct floating-point data type and replaced with 0.0.

I got the error message

> no matching signature for operator = for argument types: FLOAT64,
> STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [4.7].

I also tried using the ALTER TABLE/ COLUMN and even the CASE statement but I just can't seem to get past the error message.

I'd appreciate help from more experienced analysts who are familiar with BigQuery syntax, pls.

Comment: Are you certain the column type is not String? I'm guessing this would work b/c I think it's a string: `set unemployment_rate = '0.0' where unemployment_rate = 'NaN'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE IS_NAN(Unemployment_rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want try

```
UPDATE 
  `personal-portfolio-397412.capstone_project.2023_HY_Top_950_Youtubers`
SET Unemployment_rate = 0.0
WHERE Unemployment_rate IS NULL;
```